# Difference between the address of a pointer and the address that a pointer contains

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h> 

main() {
  int a,*p;
  a=2;
  p = &a;

  printf("The address %p contains the address of a=2:%p\n",&p,p);

  printf("The address of %d is %p\n",a,&a);

  return 0;
}
```

The result is:

> `The address 0028FF18` contains the address of `a=2: 0028FF1C`

is this correct? if not, what's the correct statement??

> The address of 2 is 0028FF1C

is this correct? if not, what's the correct statement??
    */

Comment: Yes, both statements are correct.

Comment: Technically, `0028FF1C` is the address of `a` (the value of `&a`), not the address of `2`. `a` just happens to currently contain the value of `2`.

Comment: `#include<stdio.h> //include statement` `main() {    //main function declaration` Can't get over it. This city has never been in more need of Captain Obvious.

Comment: Do note that until you actually *ask for* the address of `p` it may not actually have one (that is, it may live its entire life in a register - not in main memory). The same goes for `a`.

Comment: @AndrewMedico, not exactly.  If there's a reference to an object that is explicitly used in the code (for example, to a `const int` declaration) the compiler is forced to allocate space for it and generate the reference.  This is also applied to optimiced variables.  Perhaps you cannot get the reference in the debugger, but the compiler is forced by the standard to generate a reference in case you use it in an expression.  @csounder5 is using it explicitly in the parameter passing to printf (and the compiler doesn't know what `printf` is going to do with it, so it must be properly generated)

Answer (score 1):

p has its own address which is &p, but the value of p is the address of a.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding a:

```
printf("The value of a is %d.", a); // The value of a is 2.
printf("The address of a is %p.", &a); // The address of a is 0028FF1C
```

Regarding p:

```
printf("The value of p is the address of a is %p.", p); // The value of p is the address of a is 0028FF1C
printf("The address of p is %p.", &p); // The address of p is 0028FF18
```

I think of memory on a computer as a street full of addresses (a really *long* street), and at each address lives a single value. The variables `a` and `p` are simply syntax needed for us as programmers to conceive of these memory locations. So, `a` is a representation for the address 0028FF1C and the current resident of that address is 2 ... in the future, 2 could move out and 4 could move in, but the address would be the same.

Likewise with `p` - his address will always be 0028FF18, and it just so happens that the address of `a` is the current resident at this location, but later a different value could move in here (e.g., `p = &b`) and `p`'s address would still be 0028FF18.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the diagram below:

```
+---------+
|         |
|    2    | Value of a=2
|         |
+---------+
Address=0028FF1C


+---------+
|         |
|0028FF1C |  P stores address of a
|         |  So p=0028FF1C
+---------+
Address=0028FF18
```

So now your first question is

```
1. The address 0028FF18 contains the address of a=2: 0028FF1C. Is this correct?
```

**Answer:** Yes, it is correct as 0028FF18 is address of p and it contains &a i.e. address of a which is 0028FF1C.

Now coming to second question

```
2. The address of 2 is 0028FF1C. Is this correct?
```

**Answer:** This is little bit confusing statement (can't say it's perfectly correct) as address of a is 0028FF1C and value of a is 2. So it might be better if you print it like:

```
printf("The address of a is %p\n",&a);
```

So it will give output:

The address of a is 0028FF1C.

This statement seems better as here we are printing address of variable not the address of a value which that variable stores.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is really just a special kind of number — an address used to locate another piece of data. In your example, `p` is the numeric address to `a`, and `&p` is a pointer to the address stored in `p`. `&p` is a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

A picture is worth a thousand words, here is what p and a like in memory.

left are address, and right are variable names.

```
            +---------------+      
  0028FF18  |   0028FF1C    |  p               
            +---------------+                  
  0028FF1C  |      2        |  a                
            +---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, both are correct!

### How to understand pointer easily?

Just imagine a variable as a box with **label(variable name)** on it, and the box itself has an **address(memory address)**,such as Room 304 on 3rd floor, for anyone to locate it. In the box lays a **note(value)** tells you what it is(a `int 3`, a `char 's'`, a `float 3.14` etc).

*While a pointer is also a box with the exception that it contains a note with another box's address on it.*

#### How you read a `int`?

How it works on an variable `int a=2`?

You just say, hey I want to access `a`(the box with label a on it), someone(your compiler along with OS) just find the box and give it to you. You open the box, and see a note reading `2`(might as well as type `int`). You can change it with another note you just scribbled, say, `3`.

#### How you read a `int *`?

Similarly, say we have `int *p = a`. We get the box with label `p` on it, open it, and it says `Room 305 on 5th floor`. So instead of saying 'I want the box `a`', this time we say 'bring the box in Room 305 on 5th floor'(which is what `*p` means).

- `*p = 3;` means: bring the box which box `p` points to and change its value to 3.
- `int *q = &a`: bring a new box(put it somewhere), and fill it with a note reads the address of `a`
- `&p`: give me the address of box `p`

#### Conclusion

1. Every variable has a memory address, and a value
2. A normal variable just deals with its value directly
3. A pointer has a value points to another address(most time, the address of another variable).
4. The above *Box Model* also works on `int **p`(pointer to pointer) and more.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simple analogy will help you understand better.

```
int a = 5;
int *p = &a;
```

- `5` is the *value* of `int` variable `a`.
- `&a` is the *value* of `int *` variable `p`.
- `*p` is the `int` *value at the address* held by `int *` variable `p`.